# Usage of the word 'warming'

Tags: word-usage

I was just wondering how exactly the word *warming* is used with different sentences which actually gives different meaning.

For e.g.,

> 1. *My house warming ceremony*
> 2. *Global warming*

How it is actually giving different meaning? I understand the meaning of both, but just curious about why it is exactly as such. I would be glad if any one would explain this to me in detail about this.

Comment: As a teaching moment, I would not edit, but comment that “for e.g.” is a tautology, as “e.g.”, which is abbreviation of Latin phrase [_exempli gratia_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exempli_gratia#exempli_gratia), already means “for example”. So what are you saying is “for for example”.

Answer (score 3):

*House warming* and *global warming* don't necessarily use *warming* differently. The former refers to the warming of a house prior to occupancy while the latter refers to the warming of the entire earth. While *house warming* is now used *figuratively*, it is quite *literal* in its origins. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Housewarming_party#Origins):

> The term "housewarming" is **descended literally from the act of warming a new house**, in the days before central heating. Each guest would bring firewood, and build fires in all the available fireplaces, offering firewood as a gift. Aside from warming the house, this was also believed to repel evil spirits by creating a protective atmosphere of warmth.